# Why is VisualVM always be connecting

Tags: java, profile, visualvm

I try to use visual vm to profile my web app served with jetty.
But **Visual VM is always be connecting**... Cannot connect to the local process and show the diagram.

> My Env
>
> archlinux latest version
>
> visualVM 1.3.5
>
> Jetty8
>
> openjdk 7u17
> [image]

Comment: I wait for about 10 minutes and... finally , it connected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WTF, I wait for about 10 minutes and... finally , it connected!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following parameters to the tomcat startup:

> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8086
>
> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
>
> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

Comment: Server is jetty not tomcat.

Comment: You can use the above arguments when bootstrapping the application. Something like: java -jar <above mentioned arguments> your_jar/war_file

Comment: Hey, I am monitoring a local process, do I need such things ?

Comment: The above arguments are not needed for local java processes running under the same user as VisualVM.